# variance for weighted least squares regression

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression

$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u_i, i = 1,2,\ldots,N$. Model is heteroskedastic.
I am using an iterative version of weighted least squares, in which I iteratively perform weighted regression, then fit the resulting residuals using some nonparametric approach, and then get back to weighted regression and so on. 
Assuming that the process converges, yielding estimates $\hat{\beta}_0,\hat{\beta}_1$, how do I generate an estimate of their variances?

Answer (score 1):

The regression estimates for a weighted regression model is $$\hat{\beta} = (X'WX)^{-1}X'WY$$

Now, $Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'WX)^{-1}X'W Var(Y)W'X(X'WX)^{-1}$

Assuming $Var(u_i) = \sigma_i^2$ and $Cov(u_i,u_j)=0$ for $i\ne j$
$$Var(Y) = diag(\sigma_i^2)$$

You can use the below formulation to calculate the variance of the estimates,$$Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'WX)^{-1}X'W diag(\sigma_i^2) W'X(X'WX)^{-1}$$

Comment: This answer  ignores the uncertainty in $W$ based on the need to estimate $\sigma^2_i$.  It's fairly easy to show that the uncertainty in $W$ doesn't matter if $W$ is determined by a parameter $\alpha$ estimable at $\sqrt{n}$ rate, but that might not be enough if $W$ is determined '*using some nonparametric approach*'. I believe it is sufficient that $W$ is determined by a parameter $\alpha$ estimable at faster than $n^{1/4}$ rate, and even just consistency may be enough.